# Удалить данные из БД по кнопке

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Строки из бд выводятся в таблицу на странице. Так же для каждой строки добавляется кнопка "Удалить". Ну собственно понятно, что должна удаляться запись с соответствующим id.

Формирование таблицы:

```html
<?php
$zayavki=DB::select('select * from zayavkas where id_user=?',[Auth::user()->id]);

foreach ($zayavki as $zayava)
{
echo "<tr>";
$arr1=explode(' ',$zayava->created_at);
session(['key1' => $zayava]);
 echo "<td>$arr1[0]</td>";
 echo "<td>$zayava->cost руб.</td>";
 echo "<td>$zayava->status</td>";
 echo "<td><a href='/profile/page/{$zayava->id}'>Просмотреть</a></td>";

 echo "<td><a style='font-weight:bold; color:#ff6666; cursor: pointer' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Удалить</a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";

}

 ?>
```

Скрипт для удаления строчки на странице:

```html
function deleteRow(r)
{
var i=r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById('myTable').deleteRow(i);
}
```

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.inpdelete").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/profile/" + $(this).children("input").val(),
      method: 'get',
      data: {
        value: $(this).children("input").val()
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
<input hidden value='{$zayava->id}' name='inpdelete' id='inpdelete'/>
```

Сейчас получается, что при клике "Удалить" строка из таблицы удаляется только на странице (после обновления разумеется появляется опять). Как сделать, чтобы удалялась и из базы данных тоже?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать к примеру ajax запрос на сервер, где будет функция которая по id записи будет ее удалять. Сейчас вы удаляете ее только на стороне браузера, логично что ничего в базе данных не происходит

```
<?php
    $zayavki=DB::select('select * from zayavkas where id_user=?',[Auth::user()->id]);

    foreach ($zayavki as $zayava) {
        echo "<tr>";
        $arr1=explode(' ',$zayava->created_at);
        session(['key1' => $zayava]);
        echo "<td>$arr1[0]</td>";
        echo "<td>$zayava->cost руб.</td>";
        echo "<td>$zayava->status</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='/profile/page/{$zayava->id}'>Просмотреть</a></td>";

        echo "<td><button data-id={$zayava->id} style='font-weight:bold; color:#ff6666; cursor: pointer' class='delete'>Удалить</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
?>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function() {
        let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: `/zayava/delete/${id}`
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove()
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Добавил ещё скрипт и инпут для него. Что там исправить надо, чтобы правильно было? Ну и есть ещё отдельный php файл с командой для удаления.

Comment: Что-то не выходит. Добавил в скрипт `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = id;` и в сам файл  `<div id="id"></div>`, чтобы посмотреть отображается ли вообще что-то при клике на кнопку, но ничего не отображается.

Comment: открываете инспектор в браузере и смотрите есть ли атрибут data-id на button внутри td